# Insert sql с ошибкой #1054

Tags: mysql

Имеется таблица следующего вида:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| dateexec    | timestamp    | NO   | PRI | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| name        | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| contactname | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| phone       | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| email       | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| type_prop   | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| numcar      | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| driver      | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| timepriezd  | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| fcounty     | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| emails      | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| active      | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Пытаюсь выполнить следующий запрос:

```
INSERT INTO records (`name`, `contactname`, `phone`, `email`, `numcar`, `driver`, `emails`, `dateexec`, `timepriezd`)
VALUES ( `AAAA`, `ываыва`, `фыпвапавп`, `test@test.ru`, `а123ао234`, `sdfsdf`, `test@test.ru`, `2016-05-20 15:39:32`, `2016-05-20 15:31:00`)
```

И в результате от сервера получаю ответ об ошибке:
`#1054 -`

В чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить?

Comment: Values надо не в ` заключать, а в `'` или `"` ... и то не всегда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values надо не в ` заключать, а в ' или " ... и то не всегда